# How to create a folder with % character on SharePoint 2019 using rest calls via postman?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, postman, sharepoint-2019

I want to create a folder with % character on SharePoint 2019 and I am using the below call:

```
POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Folder"
  },
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/SP 2019/Folder%"
}
```

But this is creating a Folder%25 instead of Folder%.

If I change the character in the JSON to #, it creates a folder with '#' character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does the job.
>
> ```
> POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders/AddUsingPath(decodedurl='Path')
> ```

It will create a folder with % character. It was introduced for SP Online but also works with SP 2019.

The issue i am running into is the api returns `400 Bad Request` in two cases:
a) The folder already exists.
b) The URL is malformed.

I need to distinguish between the two.

You may take a look at this [Microsoft's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api) for further refrence.

Answer (score 0):

The value we passed in was ‘%’, but it seems that the server escaped it.
[image]

As a workaround ,you could create a event receiver(item added) . When a folder is created, if its name contains ‘%25’, rename it.
Sample code:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

        SPFolder folder = properties.ListItem.Folder;
        string name= folder.Name;
        if (name.Contains("%25")) {
            string newName=name.Replace("%25", "%");
            folder.Item["Name"] = newName;
            folder.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            folder.Item.Update();
            folder.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
    }
```

Best regards,

Amos